# How to use different numbering in multi-level lists on Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm styling my document and I need to number chapters using Roman numerals (I, II, III, …) but the sub-titles have to be all in decimal numbers, so it looks like this:

```
I. …
   1.1. …
        1.1.1. …
```

The problem is that Word uses the previous numerical notation for the next level, and it looks like this:

```
I. …
   I.1. …
        I.1.1. …
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to make a nested list is to use the "Increase Indent" button. That changes numbering automatically when you use it within a list item. Also, you can change numbering scheme easily. Right-click on any level then select "Numbering" from the menu and make your choice.

Comment: Oops. I assumed you are asking about the Numbered Lists.

Comment: Don't worry, but I'm actually trying to preserve the numbering across chapters, but using the decimal notation on subtitles

Answer (score 0):

To make a multi-level list with a unique style for the first level, you can sidestep Word's disability here by making Heading 1 a 2-point white font in the style you want all the other levels to be, followed by a line that you manually type out the way you want Level 1 to look. This requires manually writing  the visible version of Level 1 each time you add a new heading on Level 1 (and updating, if you add a new heading before previously written headings), but unless you are writing dozens of such sections in random order, this should work well.

Check out [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1258267/word-2010-give-level-1-number-different-styles-on-different-levels) that I asked after reading this one, and then figured out a similar answer for!