# Word 2010 Give Level 1 number different styles on different levels

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

As I write a document with chapters and sections within the chapters, I want the chapters to start with Heading 1, "Chapter One", and the sections to start with Heading 2, "1.1".

However, I cannot find a way to do this; it's either "Chapter 1" and "1.1 ..." or it's "Chapter One" and "One.1".

Is there a way to give different styles to the same level's number when referencing it from different levels?

I see that someone else has asked a question equivalent to this in the past, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/889948/how-to-use-different-numbering-in-multi-level-lists-on-microsoft-word-2010), but no one ever answered the question that was asked. (One answer was posted, but it was not to the question asked.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to command Word, "Use this style here and that style there", but there are ways around it.

The chapters I'm heading have extra vertical margin, so I could make Heading 1 merely a decimal number, colored white, no taller than what is being added to the margin, and then manually type in "Chapter One" and so on at the beginning of each chapter.

As long as you only need to have the beginning of each chapter different in style from references to the chapter's number, such as the headings of sections, this is not a lot of manual labor; just change Heading 1 to be small and white, change the settings for the Multi-Level List containing the chapters and the sections, create a new paragraph style to follow Heading 1 and look right, and you've pretty much got it all.

Comment: Since posting this answer, I came across something about "legal something" numbering, which puts Roman numerals on Level 1 and Persian numerals on following levels, but I was not looking for that at the time. So there may be more ways to fix this!